# Need advice for goofy Rails validation error for HTML Select element

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No matter which option I choose in this Select element, I keep getting this validation error with rails:
**Location is not included in the list**

**DB Migration**

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :location
      t.text   :notes

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
    LOCATIONS = [ '001 (Lubbock)', '002 (Odessa)', '003 (Midland)', '004 (Lubbock)' ]
    validates :name, :email, presence: true
    validates :location, inclusion: LOCATIONS

    def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
        cart.line_items.each do |item|
            item.cart_id = nil
            line_items << item
        end
    end
end
```

**Relevant Portion of the form**

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :location %><br>
   <%= f.select :location, Order::LOCATIONS,
                prompt: 'Select your location' %>
</div>
```

The select element is populating correctly, but I keep getting the validation error everytime I submit the form. Any Ideas?

**Edit 1**
(Relevant form HTML)

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="order_location">Location</label><br>
    <select id="order_location" name="order[location]"><option value="">Select your location</option>
<option value="001 (Lubbock)">001 (Lubbock)</option>
<option value="002 (Odessa)">002 (Odessa)</option>
<option value="003 (Midland)">003 (Midland)</option>
<option value="004 (Lubbock)">004 (Lubbock)</option></select>
  </div>
```

**Edit 2**
(Console output)

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-11 23:58:50 -0500
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Q+XfWgAWXQG6tD710B+3QKlwz7klsuMTG3uZKhmWwA8=", "order"=>{"name"=>"Drew Wyatt", "email"=>"test@example.com", "location"=>"002 (Odessa)", "notes"=>""}, "commit"=>"Place Order"}
  [1m[35mCart Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 46]]
Unpermitted parameters: location
  [1m[36mLineItem Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?[0m  [["cart_id", 46]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
  Rendered orders/_form.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered orders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
  [1m[35mProduct Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[36mProduct Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered line_items/_line_item.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (3.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 46ms (Views: 15.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: What is the value of each option in select tag (can you paste html source code)?

Comment: @hawk It's populated by LOCATIONS from the model. - the code that generates the HTML Select element is the final bit "Relevant Portion of the form"

Comment: Could you post the contents of the params hash?

Comment: You getting errors because value in options is not the same as Locations. Thats why I need source code, not ERB .

Comment: @pdoherty926 I'm not totally sure what you are asking for. I'm still fairly new to rails.

Comment: @hawk Is that what you needed? (edit 1)

Comment: What are the values being passed to your controller action? You should be able to tell by looking at your logs. This is the flip-side of @hawk's question.

Comment: @anwyatt Yes. First reason could be the default value (Select your location), if you submitting your form with that value you will get error. Second as @pdoherty926 already mention errors are coming from `params` hash.

Comment: @hawk this is also an issue when I submit with a valid selected option (not the default) - one second and I'll paste logs.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist the location attribute in your controller using [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

From your logs:

> Unpermitted parameters: location

Comment: I'm such a big dummy. Thank you.